# Why do I have to reinstall scikit learn in Anaconda each time I open up my Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, anaconda, conda

I have to do the following in the conda prompt before everytime I open and run my Jupyter notebook:

```
conda install scikit-learn
```

(my notebook contains the following import):

```
import sklearn
```

If I don't reinstall each time, I get the following error:

```
No module named sklearn
```

Why?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: How are you launching Jupyter? Is it from the **base** env? What env are you using as a kernel?

Comment: Do you ahve any other python installations beside anaconda? Do you have anaconda or miniconda?

Comment: Are you by any chance working inside a container or virtual machine whose environment is being reset between sessions?

Answer (score -2):

**UPDATE**

Try:

```
 conda install -c anaconda jupyter
```

Comment: I get the following: 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: then you need to install pip:https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: I downvoted this post because it casually recommends installing with `pip` in a Conda env without clearly stating the risks. Generally, Conda users should avoid using `pip`.

Comment: There should also be no need to install `pip` in an anaconda installations, something else is going on here